# Java Program Calculation

Tags: java, loops

Write a program in Java to calculate the following:
   1+2-3+4-5 …-99+100

this program is provably very simple but I am a beginner to java and this is what i have so far I'm not sure if i am in the right path

I get one java: 13 error message error:not a statement sub;

```
class Loop{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        int sum=0;
        int sum=0;
        int sub=0;

        while(num<100){

            num++;
            if(num%2 == 0){
                sum=sum+num;
            }
            sub;
            if(num%3== 0||num%5==0||num%7==0){
                sub=sub-num;
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Sum is: " +sum+sub);
    }
}
```

Comment: Is num%3== 0||num%5==0||num%7==0 to check if it is odd? If so you probably just want to go num%2 != 0 or just have it as an else to your even check

Comment: Is your series supposed to have a `+9` or a `-9`? Does your code match what you want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can using simple way to implement it :

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
    int sum = 1;
    for (int i = 2; i < 100; i++) {
        if (i % 2 == 0) {
            sum = sum + i;
        } else {
            sum = sum - i;
        }
    }
    System.out.println(sum);
}
```

Comment: i got an error message in line 12 reach end of file while parsing

Comment: what error your got？ This code should be included the public class.

Answer (score 1):

This is complaining about this line:

```
sub;
```

This is not a valid instruction, which is why the compiler is yelling at you.

Answer (score 1):

In the following:

```
if(num%2 == 0){
    sum=sum+num;
}
sub;
```

That last line `sub;` is not a Java statement. You probably want to delete it.

**Update:**

---

Looks like you want to add even and subtract odd (except for 1 which you want to add). If I understood the requirement properly:

You can start by declaring two variables as follows:

```
int sum = 1; //this will add 1
int n = 2;
```

Loop condition should be as follows:

```
while(n <= 100) { //because you want to include 100 also
```

Then on each iteration of the loop:

- If `n` is even add it to `sum`, else if `n` is odd subtract it from `sum`.
- After that increment `n` by 1.

Finally, print the value of `sum`.

Comment: what can I use instead to abbreviate substraction

Comment: @mario: It's not legal in Java to declare multiple variables with same within a block. Try to follow the update.

Answer (score 0):

```
class Loop{
   public static void main(String[] args){
   int sum=0;
   int sum=0;
   int sub=0;

    while(num<100){

     num++;
   if(num%2 == 0){
       sum=sum+num;
   }
   sub; <-- sub is not a statment
   if(num%3== 0||num%5==0||num%7==0){
       sub=sub-num;
       }
   }
   System.out.println("Sum is: " +sum+sub);
  }

}
```

You are on the right track, with a little trial and error you will get it :-) The cause of your problem is commented in the code above, in the middle of your program you have a random `sub;` on its own line. sub doesn't have a meaning in that context so the compiler doesn't know how to treat it.

Comment: what is used for substraccion then

Comment: I don't fully understand your question. Do you mean what is used for subtraction? Seeing you are doing the equivalent of x = 1+2-3+4 etc, I would try to use a single variable for that instead of trying to keep track of sum and sub separately. Also, I would look at using an `if(num%2==0) {/*Is Even*/} else {/*Is Odd*/}` approach

Answer (score 0):

Well, you declare "sum" twice, and "sub;" isn't a valid expression.

```
class Loop{
public static void main(String[] args){
    int sum=0;
    int sum=0; // second declaration? should probably be num, right? 
    int sub=0;

    while(num<100){

        num++;
        if(num%2 == 0){
            sum=sum+num;
        }
        sub; // what's this doing here?
        if(num%3== 0||num%5==0||num%7==0){
            sub=sub-num;
        }
    }
    System.out.println("Sum is: " +sum+sub);
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

1) You can't have 2 variables with the same name `sum` 
2) You need to declare and initialize a variable before you use it
3) What does the statement  `sub;` signify?

Make all the chages mentioned above and try!

Answer (score 0):

public class Loop {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int sum = 1;
    int sub = 0;

    for (int i = 2; i <= 100; i += 2)
        //sum =sum+i;
        sum +=i;

    System.out.println(sum);
    for (int i = 3; i <= 100; i += 2)
        sub += i;
    System.out.println(sub);
    System.out.println("Sum is: " +(sum-sub));
}
```

}

Try this code will give you your desired result